# How to add a face between two faces that connects them?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm having a bunch of trouble with this. I have faces going in a circle, but I want to add a face in between two of the faces to create the closed circle, but whenever I select the 4 vertices or the 2 sides, it selects every single side or vertices between the two... Making my problem. [image]

Comment: Select both opposite edges of this gap, then press "F" to fill a face between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select one vertex first and while pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> Select the other 3 vertices you want to connect, and press <kbd>F</kbd>

or

select an edge and while pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the edge to connect to and press <kbd>F</kbd>

or

select edges or vertices and do *bridge edge loop*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also it sounds like you might be hitting 'alt-click' instead of 'shift-click' to select verts/edges.  Alt-click selects a loop of verts/edges, whereas shift-click adds or subtracts single verts/edges from your current selection.